# pass xmlhttp.responseText data to php variable

Tags: php, jquery

i have a jquery that brinds text from a page through ajax and displays that text in a div
i want to pass that data to a php variable how can i do that ?

my jquery code is

```
<script type="text/javascript">
        var xmlHttp = null;
        window.onload = function() {
            xmlHttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
            xmlHttp.open("GET", "abc.php", true);
            xmlHttp.onreadystatechange = onCallback;
            xmlHttp.setRequestHeader('Content-type','application/x-www-form-urlencoded');
            xmlHttp.send(null);
        }
        function onCallback() {
            if (xmlHttp.readyState == 4) {
                if (xmlHttp.status == 200) {
                    alert(xmlHttp.responseText);
                    document.getElementById('show').innerHTML=xmlHttp.responseText;


                }
            }
        }
    </script>
```

here i want to save xmlhttp.responseTexrt in a php variable in the same file how i can do that ?

Comment: If you want to pass data from client to serverside, use an ajax call.

Comment: There is no JQuery in code, its plain Javascript! Why do you want to store it in a php variable?

Comment: the text am getting is a serialized array and after parsing the array i have to update my database so i need to store that in php variable

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Javascript is executed on the browser, and php is executed in the web server. You can not directly pass values from javascript to php.

Therefore, you need to make another ajax call (`POST`) from javascript to the web server that sends the `xmlHttp.responseText`, and write php code in the server to store the value to database.

Answer (score 0):

Pass your data in URL,

```
var data = "somedata";
xmlHttp.open("GET", "abc.php&send=" + data, true);
```

For Passing a serialized array, first convert it into string

```
var send = toString(array); 
xmlHttp.open("GET", "abc.php" + send, true);
```

For storing array to PHP variable use  `$receive =  explode(',',$_POST['send']);`